# How to dispatch an action to change initial context value in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have created a `context` for an `Overlay` component.  This context is reponsible for the `visibility` of the `Overlay`.

```
import React from "react"

const Context = React.createContext({
    visibility: false
})

export { Context }
```

My `Overlay` component visibility depends on this `context`:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { Context } from "./context"

const Overlay = ({ children }) => {

    const { visibility } = useContext(Context)
    return visibility &&
        <div className={`absolute left-0 right-0 bg-black top-0 bottom-0 bg-black-50 rounded-xl flex flex-col align-baseline justify-center items-center`}>
            {children}
        </div>
}

export default Overlay
```

In other hand, I have a `More` component which is responsible to show the `Overlay`.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { MORE_ICON } from "../../../constants/icons"
import { Context as OverlayContext } from "../Overlay/context"

const More = () => {
   // How to change the context visibility here
    return (<img
        src={MORE_ICON}
        alt="Options"
        className="ml-auto w-6 h-6 cursor-pointer"
    />)
}

export default More
```

My issue is How to change the value of the context from the `More` component ?

Comment: see https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/

Comment: @Aprillion, thank you for the post it removed the past confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd do it most of the time is pass a function in the context that allows you to change some aspect of the context. You don't have a context provider here but in your [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) wrapper you might do something like this:

```js
import { Context as OverlayContext } from "../Overlay/context";
import React from "react";

class OverlayContextProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // bind the 'this' keyword to refer to the instance of the class
        this.setVisibility = this.setVisibility.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            visibility: false,
            setVisibility: this.setVisibility
        }
    }

    setVisibility(nextValue){
        this.setState({visibility: nextValue});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <OverlayContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </OverlayContext.Provider />
        )
    }

}
```

In your `More` component you can use the function from the context to then update the context.

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { MORE_ICON } from "../../../constants/icons"
import { Context as OverlayContext } from "../Overlay/context"

const More = () => {
    const context = useContext(OverlayContext);

    return (<img
        src={MORE_ICON}
        alt="Options"
        className="ml-auto w-6 h-6 cursor-pointer"

        // You can modify it from anywhere but just using an onClick example
        onClick={() => context.setVisibility(false)}
    />)
}

export default More
```